# reducer function to check/uncheck checkboxes after clicking select all button -redux react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list of items. With each item there is a checkbox to select/deselect that particular item to add to another list.
Now user can do these things :

```
               1. By clicking 'select all' link they can select all the 
                  items.
               2. User can deselect some items from selected ones. 
               3. By clicking 'Add checked Items' button, user can add those current selected items to cart.
```

I have created action and reducer so far. I have tried to save all the checked items into a list and add that list by clicking the 'Add checked Items' button. But, i am not able to do that for unchecking and select all function.

**reducer code**

```
case 'GET_CHECKBOX':
        let newList = state.location.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode===action.payload)
        let addedItems = state.isChecked.concat(newList)
        return{
             ...state,
             isChecked:addedItems
        }
        case 'GET_CHECKED_LOCATION':
          return{
              ...state,
              conLocations:[...state.isChecked]
          }
```

**action code**

```
export const checkboxState = mruCode =>({
  type: GET_CHECKBOX,
  payload : mruCode
});

export const checkedLocation = () =>({
  type: GET_CHECKED_LOCATION
});
```

**Component Code**

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            chkitems: []
        };
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleChecklocation = this.handleChecklocation.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedAdded = this.handleCheckedAdded.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedRemove = this.handleCheckedRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleActionButton = this.handleActionButton.bind(this);
        this.checkedAllLocation = this.checkedAllLocation.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if(this.props.locationData !=null){
            this.props.initLocationData(this.props.locationData);
        }
    }
    /**componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || (JSON.stringify(nextProps.locationData) != JSON.stringify(this.props.locationData))) {
            console.log(nextProps.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
            this.props.initLocationData(nextProps.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
        }
    }*/

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || (JSON.stringify(prevProps.locationData) != JSON.stringify(this.props.locationData)))) {
            this.props.initLocationData(this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
        }
    }


    togglePanel(e) {
        this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
    }
    handleRemove(mruCode) {
        this.props.removeLocation(mruCode)
    }
    handleClick(mruCode) {
        this.props.addLocation(mruCode)
    }
    allLocations() {
        this.props.addAllLocation()
    }
    clearall() {
        this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }

    handleChecklocation(mruCode) {
        this.props.checkboxState(mruCode);
    }

    handleCheckedAdded() {
        this.props.checkedLocation()
    }

    checkedAllLocation(){
        this.props.selectAllBoxes()
    }

    /** updating locationData by saving changes - calling this function into jobsPanel */
    getLocationData() {
        let saveableLocationlist = [];
        if (this.props.conLocations != null) {
            const { conLocations } = this.props;
            saveableLocationlist = conLocations;
        }
        const locationData = {
            locationDetails: saveableLocationlist
        }
        return locationData;
    }

    render() {
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return (
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e) => this.togglePanel(e)}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                            <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                            <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.props.conLocations.map((loc, index) => <span key={index}>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}{index < this.props.conLocations.length - 1 ? ',\u00A0' : ''}</span>)}
                                <span onClick={(e) => this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {this.state.open ? (
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <div className="row grid-divider">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <div className="col-padding"><div className="pos-div"><h4>Locations List</h4><a data-target="toggle" data-target="#myCheckbox" className="jdClickable1" onClick={()=>this.checkedAllLocation()}>Select all</a><button style={{ display: this.props.location.length === this.props.conLocations.length ? "none" : "block" }} className="allLargeBtn" onClick={() => this.allLocations()}>Add Checked Locations</button></div><hr />
                                    {this.props.location.map((item, index) => (
                                        <div key={index}><div><input type="checkbox" /><label></label><span className="locationNameSpan">{item.mruCode} - {_labels[item.division]} - {item.country}</span>{!this.props.conLocations.find(item2 => item.mruCode === item2.mruCode) && (<div className="pull-right jd"><button className="call-to-action" onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.mruCode)}>Add Location</button></div>)}<hr /></div></div>))}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>) : null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        location: state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations: state.locationRed.conLocations,
        isChecked: state.locationRed.isChecked
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return  bindActionCreators({
        loadData,
        addLocation,
        addAllLocation,
        removeLocation,
        removeAllLocation,
        checkboxState,
        checkedLocation,
        initLocationData,
        selectAllBoxes
    },  dispatch);
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(NewLocationPanel);
```

how to write select all function and deselect using flags. **mruCode** is the primary id for every item in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
case 'UNCHECK_ITEM':
{
  const newList = state.isChecked.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode !== action.payload)
  return{
    ...state,
    isChecked: newList
  }
}
case 'CHECK_ALL_ITEMS':
{
  return{
    ...state,
    isChecked: state.location
  }
}

export const uncheckItem = mruCode =>({
  type: UNCHECK_ITEM,
  payload : mruCode
});

export const checkAllItems = () =>({
  type: CHECK_ALL_ITEMS
});
```

Comment: Thanks Philip ... I understood properly. But, i need selected items. How to remove uncheck items and get the selected item list.

Comment: If you want to get those items inside component, you need to use connect from 'react-redux' library.

Comment: i have updated my component. But how to display checkboxes checked while clicking 'Select all' link. selectAllBoxes() is same as yours checkAllItems()